# PHP PDO SQLSERVER Output Parameters Issue

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
$query = '  Declare @MemCode Varchar(12);
        Declare @ConCounter decimal(28,0);
        Set @MemCode = null;
        Set @ConCounter = null; 
        EXECUTE spQMInsEventMember_TMS 
        "'.$masterEventCode.'",
        "'.$eventCode.'",
        '.$memberContactTitle.',
        "'.$guestFirstName.'",
        "'.$guestLastName.'",
        '.$address.',
        '.$townDescription.',
        '.$countryCode.',
        '.$postZip.',
        '.$STD.',
        '.$phone.',
        "'.$guestEmail.'",
        '.$isMember.',
        '.$divisionCode.',
        '.$statusCode.',
        '.$subStatusCode.',
        '.$memberTypeCode.',
        '.$memberTitles.',
        '.$memberSubType.',
        '.$classCode.',
        '.$subClassCode.',@MemCode OUTPUT,@ConCounter OUTPUT; 
        SELECT @MemCode AS member_code;
        SELECT @ConCounter AS contact_counter;';
        //print_r($query);

        $res = $this->dbh->query($query); 
        $result = $res->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);
```

The Stored Procedure runs fine, if I run it on SQLSERVER, I gets 2 Rows.
But when I run it from the PHP, I do not get the member_code or contact_counter returned in the results array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly because of multiple select statements?  If your query is working in sql but not in PHP, you should try printing out your parameters to see if they are being set properly.

Comment: Removed the multiple select statements so there is only one.

Comment: The Stored Proc runs from PHP, (makes insert/updates to tables) but the two OUTPUT pararmeters are not returned in the results array?

Comment: Did you try Declare \@MemCode Varchar(12) = null;
        Declare \@ConCounter decimal(28,0) = null;

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help. I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.
It's stumping me as well.